# c# Web App - Encoding' does not contain a definition for 'UTF8

Tags: c#, .net, iis

IIS Website on Server 2016.

```
using System.Text

string x = "abcdefg";
byte[] y = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x);
```

Results in:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'Encoding' does not contain a definition for 'UTF8'
```

It isn't complaining that "`Encoding`" is undefined, but that `.UTF8` in the Encoding class is undefined.

Works fine on my own desktop running IIS Express in Visual Studio, but when deployed to Server, gives the above error message.

My local dev machine has: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Server has only Microsoft .NET Runtime 5.0.9 and Microsoft ASP.NET Core 5.0.9.  In fact, the server does not have any version of .NET **Framework** installed, yet all other web apps (mine and others) are working fine.

Can I install and run .NET Framework 4.7 alongside .NET Runtime 5?  And should it be necessary in the first place?  Does .NET Runtime 5 not include Encoding.UTF8?

Thanks.

EDIT: There is nothing wrong with this code.  This is a question of framework dependencies or interrelations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the .NET Framework on the server ultimately fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76246218/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).